# Replacement for Dependency Injection Container in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dependency-injection

I have read dozens of articles about this and still have some questions.

How are services used in multiple parts of the system?  For example, I have a permissions component that is used by several other classes during a request.  Right now, I have made it a singleton.  **I have been using singletons as the entry point to portions of my domain (various services) that need to be reused during a request.** This seems to be the only way I can access these services in different parts of the system without reinstantiating them or without throwing them in a global variable.  In other systems, I would make it a normal class and set it's lifecycle to "request".  The container would make sure that it is shared within the request and release it for garbage collection.

I have thought about using a service locator which stores services in **Thread.current**.  But this feels like I'm getting desperate.

The main way I've seen that people accessing these dependencies is to wrap the dependency in a method:

```
class A
  def some_dep
     SomeService.instance
  end
end
```

In tests, `some_dep` is overridden to return a mock or whatever.  This seems like the best so far but still feels hackish.

**My options for using services within a request seem to be:**

1) Put them in a global variable / Thread.current.

2) Use a service locater.

3) Pass dependencies around manually (complete disaster).

4) Singleton.

**Two questions:**

1) What is the best approach for making services available to multiple parts of the system without reinstantiating?

2) What is the best approach for a class to manage those dependencies?

**Note:**
I understand that I can put reusable functionality into modules.  IMO, however, modules are great for purposes of staying DRY but not for carrying state around the system (i.e. which tenant you're on in a multitenant application).

Comment: DI's never really taken off in Ruby/Rails. Some people say it's because dynamic languages don't need it, but the popularity of AngularJS shows otherwise.  If you're looking for a best practice answer, it will be hard to come across as there really isn't one afaict.

Comment: As far as scoping objects to the request, it's usually not needed because the controller is already scoped to the request. So any attributes you make, e.g. `@thing_factory = ThingFactory.new` will be accessible in controller methods and scoped to the request.

Comment: I'm not totally sure why.  DI is great for IOC for testing but this isn't the only benefit.  If you're using a good DIC, it will not only inject those deps, but will also manage object lifecycle.  A good DIC is not only a dependency injection container but a dependency manager.

Comment: I tend to agree Ruby/Rails could overall benefit from more DI conventions and libs.

Comment: One other point is that Rails is built on Rack, so it's typical for many libraries to use the Rack environment as a common request scope.